# URLComponents @ is not encoded

Tags: ios, swift, url

```
import UIKit

func createUrl() {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "services-test.abc.pippo.com"
    components.path = "/first/second/third"
    components.queryItems = createQueryItems()

    // Getting a URL from our components is as simple as
    // accessing the 'url' property.
    let url = components.url
    print("createUrl: \(String(describing: url!))\n\ncomponents: \(components), queryItems: \(components.queryItems)")
}

func createQueryItems() -> [URLQueryItem] {
    var items: [URLQueryItem] = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "amznToken", value: "asfdsfadfasads"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "UID", value: "sdsadasdasdasd"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "login_ID", value: "pippo.pluto@gmail.com"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "ssoEnabled", value: "true"),
    ]

    items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "country", value: "IT"))

    return items
}

createUrl()
```

This prints:

```
createUrl: https://services-test.abc.pippo.com/first/second/third?amznToken=asfdsfadfasads&UID=sdsadasdasdasd&login_ID=pippo.pluto@gmail.com&ssoEnabled=true&country=IT

components: https://services-test.abc.pippo.com/first/second/third?amznToken=asfdsfadfasads&UID=sdsadasdasdasd&login_ID=pippo.pluto@gmail.com&ssoEnabled=true&country=IT
 
queryItems: Optional([amznToken=asfdsfadfasads, UID=sdsadasdasdasd, login_ID=pippo.pluto@gmail.com, ssoEnabled=true, country=IT])
```

So the @ is not encoded, if I use Alamofire it is encoded.
If I try to encode the string passed in the query item its encoded two times, so how to encode the @?

Comment: Percent-Encoding of `@` is optional, since it is not a reserved character in the query part.

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 3986, the "@" character is valid in a query string, so the correct behavior would be not to encode it. Refer to Apple's query​Items [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents/1407752-queryitems) and Wikipedia's [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more information

The solution in your case would be to either encode the queryItems manually,

```
components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "%40")
```

or alter the behavior of Apple's percent encoding APIs

```
var urlQueryAllowedCharacters = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
urlQueryAllowedCharacters.remove("@")

components.percentEncodedQuery = createQueryItems().map {
    // Unwrap safely if needed
    let name = $0.name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: urlQueryAllowedCharacters)!
    let value = $0.value!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: urlQueryAllowedCharacters)!
    return "\(name)=\(value)"
}.joined(separator: "&")
```